# perform operation opposite to pandas ffill

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'player': ['LBJ', 'LBJ', 'LBJ', 'Kyrie', 'Kyrie', 'LBJ', 'LBJ'],
                   'points': [25, 32, 26, 21, 29, 21, 35]})
```

How can I perform the operation opposite of [ffill](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) so I can get the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'player': ['LBJ', np.nan, np.nan, 'Kyrie', np.nan, 'LBJ', np.nan],
                   'points': [25, 32, 26, 21, 29, 21, 35]})
```

That is, I want to fill directly repeated values with NaN.

Here's what I have so far but I'm hoping there's a built-in pandas method or a better approach:

```
for i, (index, row) in enumerate(df.iterrows()):
    if i == 0:
        continue
    go_back = 1
    while True:
        past_player = df.ix[i-go_back, 'player']
        if pd.isnull(past_player):
            go_back += 1
            continue
        if row['player'] == past_player:
            df.set_value(index, 'player', value=np.nan)
        break
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ffinv = lambda s: s.mask(s == s.shift())
df.assign(player=ffinv(df.player))

  player  points
0    LBJ      25
1    NaN      32
2    NaN      26
3  Kyrie      21
4    NaN      29
5    LBJ      21
6    NaN      35
```

Comment: I knew there had to be a better way :)

Comment: Great answer. The lambda function is a more elegant way to say `df['player'] = df['player'].mask(df['player'] == df['player'].shift())`

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most efficient solution but working would be to use `itertools.groupby` and `itertools.chain`:

```
>>> df['player'] = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([key] + [float('nan')]*(len(list(val))-1) 
                        for key, val in itertools.groupby(df['player'].tolist())))
>>> df
  player  points
0    LBJ      25
1    NaN      32
2    NaN      26
3  Kyrie      21
4    NaN      29
5    LBJ      21
6    NaN      35
```

More specifically this illustrates how it works:

```
for key, val in itertools.groupby(df['player']):
    print([key] + [float('nan')]*(len(list(val))-1))
```

giving:

```
['LBJ', nan, nan]
['Kyrie', nan]
['LBJ', nan]
```

which is then "chained" together.

Answer (score 0):

sort *data* by **players** and use `np.where` to fill in `NaN` values.

```
df_sorted = df.sort_values('player')
df_sorted['player'] = np.where(df_sorted['player'].duplicated(), 
                               np.nan,
                               df_sorted['player']
                              )
```

`>>>df_sorted.reset_index(drop=True)`

[image]